# Read File using JXL with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jxl

I am needing to read a excel file using lib JXL with UTF-8 Encoding.

I already try using WorkbookSettings as bellow:

```
 WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
 ws.setEncoding("UTF-8");
 Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(fileInputStream,ws);
```

But didn't work.

I also try to convert the output string to utf-8 using the bytes as bellow:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString);
String value = new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

But still doesn't work:

This is my output:

Can you help me?

[image: output here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the problem changing the WorkbookSettings to:

```
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings(); 
ws.setEncoding("Cp1252");
```

I belived it is the format the file is.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed...thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the JXL encoding as parameter for the JVM:

```
-Djxl.encoding=ISO-8859-1
```